# test if hostname exists from command line without ping

Tags: linux, bash, ip, host

we have a script that needs to take action on a finite list of hosts.  but every time we add or remove a host to the /etc/hosts file, we end up having to update this script.

basically, say my hosts file looks like:

```
192.168.100.1     hostip_1
192.168.100.2     hostip_2
192.168.100.10    hostip_3
192.168.100.20    hostip_5
```

and my script (bash) does something like:

```
callmyfunction hostip_1
callmyfunction hostip_2
callmyfunction hostip_3
callmyfunction hostip_5
```

if i want to add hostip_4 to the list of hosts, i now have to go in and edit my script and add it to the list.  while it's a small edit, it is still a step that can be forgotten in the process (especially if someone new to the system comes in).

is there a way i can test to see if 'hostip_1' is a valid hostname within the system (without pinging the host or grepping the /etc/hosts file)?  we may use multiple hosts files, and different configurations may have different filenames, so i can't rely on trying to grep a single file.  i need the system to do that work for me.

any clues?

Comment: have you tried `nslookup hostip_1` (or the more modern `dig hostip_1`)?  sounds like what you really need is to set up your own local DNS server...

Comment: both of those need DNS.  i ended up answering my own question.  thanks for looking at this though.  i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

first, my statement about things not being in the hosts file is wrong.  that is exactly where they are.  dumb on my part.

but the answer is:

```
getent hosts
```

that will get it to print everything out, and i can do a lookup from there.

Comment: Actually, you can get `getent` to do the lookup for you: `getent hosts www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: you're right.  i was doing a `getent hosts | grep -c myhost1_ip` thing, but just shortened it to `getent hosts myhost1_ip`.  check to see if you get a blank string or not (result), and you've got the answer.

Comment: You don't even need to check the result as a string: getent returns non-zero if the host is not found -- `if getent hosts $name; then echo "$name is in hosts"; else echo "$name not found"; fi`

Comment: Why not : ``for name in `getent hosts | grep 'host_ip[[:digit:]]\+' | awk '{ print $2 }'` ; do callmyfunction $name ; done``

Comment: Note that `getent hosts` is not limited to searching `/etc/hosts`.  While `getent hosts` on its own lists the entries in `/etc/hosts`, `getent hosts <hostname>` will check _all_ sources of hostname information for `<hostname>`; it will return values from `/etc/hosts`, DNS if configured, mdns if configured, and anything else you have configured for resolving hostnames.  It uses `gethostbyaddr` directly to resolve the name.

Answer (score 1):

As you are populating the /etc/hosts file, I am assuming that you are not using DNS. So below solution wont fit your use case. But it will still get you some pointers.

In a working DNS environment, you can check the host name to its corresponding IP with below command

```
# host host_name
```

This is will give the IP address of the host. In case the host name does not exists, then it will give you corresponding host not found message.

You can parse the output of above command and can deduce whether a give host name exists.

Comment: sorry, these are internal IPs not tied into DNS.  should've specified that.

Comment: getent hosts <hostname> or <address> as suggested by @thkala works with both the hosts file and configured name services such as DNS and NIS. The search order is typically controlled by /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Answer (score 1):

might not be in your /etc/hosts file... better search for the name and see if an ip can be found:

```
(($(dig +noall +answer google.de |wc -c)>0)) && echo exists
```

this is bash, can be adaptet to pretty much everything.

```
dig +noall +answer google.de
```

returns the ips if found. If empty, that name cannot be used in the computer running this code.

Comment: thanks. but as you said, it doesn't work for `/etc/hosts` ... is there any way to include all cases?

Answer (score 0):

If all the targets are on the same subnet (same network), use `arping`, it will check that hosts are available using [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol).

Comment: this is a less than desirable solution, because i was trying to do so without creating any extra network traffic.  but it's a solution nonetheless, and thanks for the contribution.

Comment: ARP traffic is very limited compared to ping traffic. And ARP is required for ping and any other network exchange involving Ethernet and IPv4. But `getent hosts` is the way to go to use /etc/hosts as your list of target.